# Why can't I join threads containing a for loop in Scala 3?

Tags: multithreading, scala, scala-3

Why does only this specific code break when everything else works?

No problems when commenting out the for loop OR join(). Just doesn't work with both.

Using a while loop works, putting the loop in another class also works, works in the REPL or as a script without wrapping it as an object/class (using @main), works in Scala 2. Doesn't work with a loop in a function in the same class/object

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val t = new Thread() {
    override def run() = {
      println("Started")
      for (j <- 1 to 2) {println("Work")}
    }
  }
  t.start()
  t.join()
}
```

Edit:

By doesn't work I mean unexpected behavior: Nothing in the loop or after the loop executes.
Also replacing join() with Thread.sleep(3000), the new thread (containing the for loop) continues executing (starting off at the for loop) only after the main thread finishes sleeping

It can be tested in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sGPSxgYSSRO4t2IGL2qAJw)

Iterating over any collection seems to cause the problem. For can be replaced with this block and it still won't print

```scala
it = List(1, 2, 3)
it.foreach(x => println(x))
```

But this will print, which shouldn't work because this is the definition of foreach

```scala
it = List(1, 2, 3)
while(it.hasNext) println(it.next())
```

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please include those details, also, can you try creating a **Scastie** that reproduces the problem? - Finally, any specific reason to use low level threads with **Scala**?

Comment: Unexpected behavior, no error but nothing after or inside the loop executes, no response after entering the loop, program has to be terminated after. It was also tested with Scastie before asking which confirmed it works in Scala 2 but not Scala 3 (paste only the contents of the main function). I was translating some java, no real necessity to use low level threads it was just weird to me how specific the problem was.

Comment: It works for me both in **Scala 2**and in **Scala 3** as you can see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/LUtziZ6WTKmE8mmOzWFqCg/1) - Maybe the issue was just that your `main` was badly defined?

Comment: Sorry my mistake works with correct main definition, but with "Main extends App" or without main wrapper [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sGPSxgYSSRO4t2IGL2qAJw) I get the problem

Comment: Try moving out lambda definition outside object. I suspect it's a class-loader deadlock:  classloader starts initializing `Main`, `Main` calls constructor when it's initialized, **constructor waits lambda, this lambda depends on classloader returning initialized `Main`**, thus deadlock. See https://twitter.com/shipilev/status/1471216975485579267

Comment: If it's classloader deadlock you can solve the issue by: removing lambda, moving lambda outside, removing `join()`, removing `extends App` and implementing own `def main` to NOT have circular dependency on initialization (`App` rewrites code and here you have an example why it's bad).

Comment: That's it, thank you! The [tweet](https://twitter.com/shipilev/status/1471216975485579267) looks like the same problem. If you want you can add it as the answer so I can mark it right

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped. I can write an answer but later on, I'm afk atm.

Comment: Don't use `App`, it was a bad idea _(done with good intentions)_ shouldn't be used in **Scala 2**, even less in **Scala 3**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scala 3 no longer treats `DelayedInit` the way Scala 2 did](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html), with the result that the body of an `App` now executes as part of the static initializer (as it would for any other `object`).  Any thread apart from the one that loads the class will block until such time as the static initializer finishes (in this case, the static initializer exits before the synthetic `main` method from `App` is even called).

In the case of `Seq(1, 2).foreach { _ => println("Working") }`, the body of `{ _ => println("Working") }` is hoisted out into being part (likely a method, though I haven't inspected the bytecode) of the enclosing `Main` object and thus the call to `foreach` blocks until `Main` is a "real object" in the eyes of the JVM, which isn't until the static initializer finishes.  Unfortunately, the static initializer (thanks to the `join`) is waiting for `foreach` to finish.  `while` is still specially interpreted by the compiler and turns into a loop in the bytecode.

This can be seen by the minimal change of not extending `App` and only moving the call to `join` into a main method, as in [this Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/q0QhWxPmQKaDscYwCkbEWQ).  The static initializer forks the thread and is finished (making `Main` a real object in the eyes of the JVM and thus allowing the `foreach` in the forked thread to execute).  After this, the main method is entered and is able to `join` the forked thread.